# How to destroy crisp chat

Tags: javascript, meteor

when I go to the administration of my application which is a single page application, I want to destroy crisp, I don't want a crisp employee to know what I'm doing in my admin...

the only way I found is $crisp.push(["do", "session:reset", [true]]); which forces me to refresh the page, does anyone know another way to do this?

there is a method $crisp.push(["do", "chat:hide"]) but why not $crisp.push(["do", "chat:destroy"]) or similar?

why is it so complicated to destroy crisp?